# JavaFX to monitor/record events performed on a web page

Tags: java, javafx

I have a requirement to record events performed on a web page.

Eg. Filling registration form.

Recorder should capture the keyword entries and clicks performed on the page and play back when requested. At time same time recorder should also capture the actual element that generates the event.
Say when i key in the firstName in

> `<input type="text" id="f_name"/>`

recorder should be able to capture the id 'f_name'

I was wondering if I could use JavaFX for that!?. JavaFX is allowing me to load a page and I could detect various operations performed on the page by registering the appropriate event listeners. But it is not giving me any useful information about which element in the page has created that event.

```
   package test1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class JSTEst2 extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                //if the page is loaded

                JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", this);
                //System.out.println(engine.executeScript("document.querySelector('body').innerHTML"));
                //engine.executeScript("document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) { alert(event.target.id); app.getCallBack(event.target.id);}, false);");
                engine.executeScript("document.addEventListener('click', function(event) { alert(event.target.id); app.getCallBack(event.target.id);}, false);");
            }
        });



        /*engine.loadContent(
                "<html><body>"
                + " <ul class=\"ct\">"
                + "<li id=\"first\">first</li>"
                + "<li id=\"second\">second</li>"
                + " <li id=\"third\">third</li>"
                + "</ul>"
                + "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Add <li>\" />"
                + "</body>"
                + "</html>"
        );*/

        engine.load("<my_url>");


        //String javascript = "document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') { console.log(event.target.id);   alert(event.target.id); }});";


        engine.setOnAlert(event -> showAlert(event.getData()));
        engine.setConfirmHandler(message -> showConfirm(message));



        //engine.executeScript(javascript);


        VBox root = new VBox();

        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        root.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +

                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +

                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +

                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +

                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +

                "-fx-border-color: blue;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();

    }


      private void showAlert(String message) {
            Dialog<Void> alert = new Dialog<>();
            alert.getDialogPane().setContentText(message);
            alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
            alert.showAndWait();
        }

        private boolean showConfirm(String message) {
            Dialog<ButtonType> confirm = new Dialog<>();
            confirm.getDialogPane().setContentText(message);
            confirm.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
            boolean result = confirm.showAndWait().filter(ButtonType.YES::equals).isPresent();

            // for debugging:
            System.out.println(result);

            return result ;
        }

private void getCallBack(String data) {
    System.out.println("---->" + data);
}



}
```

When i clicked on 'firstname' input field,
[image]

the sys out in the listener printed something like this,

```
WebView@90e64cf[styleClass=web-view]
javafx.scene.Scene@52fca713
```

which I can hardly interpret.

Is JavaFX he right approach is this case?
If Yes, how do i get the required information using JavaFX?

**##################UPDATE##################**

I have updated the code to use **executeScript()** method. Now it shows the target element id in alert box, but i need to communicate it back to my java application. The logic I have in the code is not working.  Any thoughts!!?

Comment: Try to get informations by javascript. Using this method: webEngine.executeScript(JScript);

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski Thanks, that helped!!. is there someway we can get a call back to the invoking java class? I tried some logic, but dint worked!!. updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Do you have some outputs from getCallBack(String data)?

Comment: getCallBack(String data) does not have any return value. i just want the 'id' of the element to be printed there..Currently that is not happening..

Comment: Change private void getCallBack(String data) to public, do you have any errors in webrowser console?

Comment: I did this using a `List` of custom objects that simply captured keystrokes, mouse press,  and mouse locations and it worked perfectly.

Comment: ehhh!!!!... i should have followed the rules of java. simply copied a random method from somewhere. dint checked the access!! Thanks @MaciejPulikowski

Comment: No problem :) I reply to a question, if everything works, you can close thread.

Comment: Sure, Done!!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get informations about events from website, you can call methods from **Javascript** to your **WebEngine**:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

Engine.executeScript("document.cookie");
```

To have a 2-way communication between **Javascript** and **Java**. You have to set member for window and create method to call it in **Javascript**. Full working script:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class JSTEst2 extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                //if the page is loaded

                JSObject window = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", this);
                engine.executeScript("document.addEventListener('click', function(event) { alert(event.target.id); app.getCallBack(event.target.id);}, false);");
            }
        });

        engine.load("<my_url>");
        engine.setOnAlert(event -> showAlert(event.getData()));
        engine.setConfirmHandler(message -> showConfirm(message));

        VBox root = new VBox();

        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        root.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +

                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +

                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +

                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +

                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +

                "-fx-border-color: blue;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();

    }


        private void showAlert(String message) {
            Dialog<Void> alert = new Dialog<>();
            alert.getDialogPane().setContentText(message);
            alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
            alert.showAndWait();
        }

        private boolean showConfirm(String message) {
            Dialog<ButtonType> confirm = new Dialog<>();
            confirm.getDialogPane().setContentText(message);
            confirm.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
            boolean result = confirm.showAndWait().filter(ButtonType.YES::equals).isPresent();

            // for debugging:
            System.out.println(result);

            return result ;
        }

        public void getCallBack(String data) {
            System.out.println("---->" + data);
        }

    }

}
```